# how to add jcomments to my custom module?

Tags: comments, joomla2.5

I have created a module in joomla 2.5. In that module I am displaying one article at a time getting its id from the url and then query the database for that id and displaying the article  title and content.

I want to display also the comment form under the content of the article so that a user can add a comment to that article.

I am using the Jcomments module.

Below the content area I have placed the following code for displaying the jcomments form but it is not displaying .

```
<?php

 $comments = 'components/com_jcomments/jcomments.php';
  if (file_exists($comments)) {
    require_once($comments);
?>
<center>
<div class="mtframe">
    <?php echo JComments::showComments($article->id, 'mod_article_detail', $article->title);?>
</div>
</center>
```

So how will add the jcomment form to my custom module?

Comment: Are there any errors / warnings? And, is `<div class="mtframe>` included in the page output? If not, add some static content before the first line to see whether the script is executed.

Comment: yes the `<div class="mframe">` included in page output but nothing to display in it. No errors and no warnings.

Answer (score 0):

As for no warnings are shown, they may be disabled. You should remove the `if` check as because error should occur when the file is not found.

Also, specify an absolute path:

```
$comments = JPATH_SITE.'/components/com_jcomments/jcomments.php';
```

To be sure then, you could add some debugging lines (but I'd suggest not to make the module usable to the public, then):

```
var_dump(class_exists('JComments'));
var_dump(is_callable(array('JComments', 'showComments'));
var_dump($article->id);
```

Comment: I echo the `$comments` variable and the use the var_dump as you defined. It display these contents `C:\wamp\www\sportingbalance/components/com_jcomments/jcomments.php

boolean true

boolean true

string '75' (length=2)
`

Comment: Oh I see, the `showComments` may only called once per page, so if there are already comments shown in the content, this will not work. Instead, you may call the function  `JComments::getCommentsForm`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now the with `JComments::getCommentsForm` displays on my page. But When I add comments to that article and publish it from the admin side, It should appear with the article but in my case it is no displaying. Whats the problem?

Comment: And also the comments are not inserting to the database :(

Comment: Ok, the form may be only used once, too, because it uses ids. Additionally, there seems to be no simple method to enter a commment by a POST form (it requires java script), so I can't help you without spending much more time on it. Sorry for that.